# Check the difference in one column based on duplicated values in other two column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example data frame like this.

```
animal  color  price
rabit   red    10
turtle  green  15
rabit   red    12
turtle  green  15
turtle  green  10
sheep   white  5
sheep   white  5
```

If the values in animal and color are the same like row 1 and row 3 but price is different, return the rows with different price. Results shoule be something like this:

```
animal  color  price
rabit   red    10
rabit   red    12
turtle  green  15
turtle  green  10
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the appropriate tags this could be pandas, pyspark or something else

Comment: Hi, I'm new to python so I'm not familiar with the packages. Any function could solve the problem will be fine.

Comment: you are using pandas Dataframe right? do you have an `import pandas as pd` at the top of your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas and numpy

Comment: Added a solution and a detailed explanation to the reason why order of using the 2 statements matters. Do mark the answer if it solved your issue! Thanks!

Comment: @CouchTomato, did the solution by Veedata work for you? it's actually giving an incorrect result. Any reason why you market that as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

Make sure to use the `drop_duplicates()` first, before using `pd.duplicated` with `keep=False`, for your intended purpose.

```
out = df.drop_duplicates()
out = out[out.duplicated(subset=['animal','color'], keep=False)]
print(out)
```

```
   animal  color  price
0   rabit    red     10
1  turtle  green     15
2   rabit    red     12
4  turtle  green     10
```

---

**NOTE!!:** If you use `drop_duplicates()` as the second step, you get the unexpected output as below.

```
out = df[df.duplicated(subset=['animal','color'], keep=False)]
out = out.drop_duplicates()
print(out)
```

```
   animal  color  price
0   rabit    red     10
1  turtle  green     15
2   rabit    red     12
4  turtle  green     10
5   sheep  white      5
```

---

#### Why does this happen?

Intuitively, `drop_duplicates()` removes duplicates based on all the columns together and `df.duplicated(keep=False)` marks all duplicates based on the 2 given columns.

**Scenario 1:** Remove all rows that have the same 2 columns and price, then keep the duplicates based on 2 columns > This means you will be left with rows with different prices but duplicate 2 columns.

**Scenario 2:** Keep all rows that are duplicated based on 2 columns (which would not remove anything in this example). Then drop duplicate rows where the price is the same. Ends up being the same as just dropping duplicate rows across all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `duplicated` function to get the output you require. Once you have done that, you can use the drop_duplicates function to eliminate rows that are completely similar.

```
duplicates = df[df.duplicated(subset=['animal','color', keep = False)]
duplicates = duplicates.drop_duplicates()

print(duplicates)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it also shows the deplicated price. I want to only return the different value in price like shown in the result.

Comment: I have updated my answer satisfy that condition @CouchTomato

Comment: This will not work either. the duplicates need to be dropped first, and then df.duplicated with work properly. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Why will the order of dropping duplicates make a difference?

Comment: I have added an explanation. You can run both step by step and see how the boolean's are returned for both the versions.

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense once I see it like that!

Comment: I have added a more detailed explanation as well as to why this happens.